# JavaScript invalid date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm being passed a date that is 'date time UTC' such as `2012-03-10 20:00:00 UTC`. How can I parse that using Javascript's Date so that I can get the time until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.parse` can do it:

```
new Date(Date.parse('2012-03-10 20:00:00 UTC'))
```

At least, it can on Google Chrome. If you find any compatibility problems, this will do the trick instead:

```
function parseDate(date) {
    var m = /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) UTC$/.exec(date);
    var tzOffset = new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5], +m[6]).getTimezoneOffset();

    return new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5] - tzOffset, +m[6]);
}
```

Comment: That returns Invalid Date because Date.parse returns NaN.

Comment: @Chris: Well, it works for me :) Here, I added a more compatible solution. (But it's not playing well with DST at the moment, give me a minute...)

Comment: Indeed it works on Chrome, while FF 17 returns invalid date. Not surprising seeing the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). AFAIK parsing date with `.parse` is very platform-dependent.

Comment: I was trying it on Safari. Your regex solution works, thanks! Was hoping JS would be able to handle this but I guess Dates are always hard due to myriad formats.